# Changing password with asp .net security

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, passwords

I have a problem with the change password, i Have the method to change:

```
public async Task ChangeMyPasswordAsync(string password, string oldPassword)
{
    var identity = await UserManager.FindAsync((Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Name, oldPassword);
    if (identity == null)
        throw new AuthenticationException();

    CheckError(await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(identity.Id));
    CheckError(await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(identity.Id, password));
}
```

If you show the table in BBDD the hash of the password is changed but when I am trying to log in the application I see this line:

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
```

in the user variable have the HASH of the old password, but when i reset the app (Shift + F5 and F5 again) I can't use the new password and no the old...

Any idea please??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ChangePassword method instead of deleting a password and adding a new one.

```
public async Task ChangeMyPasswordAsync(string password, string oldPassword)
{
    var identity = await UserManager.FindAsync((Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Name, oldPassword);
    if (identity == null)
        throw new AuthenticationException();

    CheckError(await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(identity.Id, oldPassword, password));
}
```

See Microsoft documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497523(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: In my context your solution is not valid, thanks for your help